# Сгенерировать последовательность

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, коллекции, список

Даются два числа, например 3 и 4 и нужно сгенерировать последовательность 
1,2,3,8,9,10,15,16,17
то есть, первое число - сколько цифр вставляем, второе - сколько пропускаем.
Как бы это сделать попроще?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы выводить `run` чисел подряд, пропуская `jump` чисел по кругу:

```
import itertools

def generate(run, jump, start=1):
    for i in itertools.count(start, run + jump):
        yield from range(i, i + run)
```

Пример:

```
>>> list(itertools.islice(generate(3, 4), 9))
[1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython_stdlib.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
import itertools
    
def generate(run, jump, start=1):
        for i in itertools.count(start, run + jump):
            yield from range(i, i + run)
    
# try your own input    
from browser import document, html
@document["mybutton"].bind("click")
def on_click(event):
    run = int(document['run'].value)
    jump = int(document['jump'].value)
    seq = list(itertools.islice(generate(run, jump), 9))
    document <= html.P(f'{run}, {jump} -> {seq}')
</script><label for="run">run: <input id="run" value="3" size=3><label for="jump"> jump: <input id="jump" value="4" size=3> <button id="mybutton">generate(run, jump)</button></body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
number = 3
pass_num = 4
i = 1

items = []

for _ in range(number):
    # Вставляем
    for _ in range(number):
        items.append(i)
        i += 1

    # Пропускаем
    i += pass_num

print(items)
```

Результат:

```
[1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17]
```

Comment: почему бы `i += pass_num` не написать?¶ Не ясно почему внешний цикл ограничен, а не `while True: ..yield i..`

Comment: недооптимизировал :D

Answer (score 0):

```
generate = 3
skip = 4
n = 50
my_list = []
g = generate
s = skip
for i in range(1, n):
  if g == 0 and s == 0:
    g = generate
    s = skip
  if g > 0:
    g -= 1
    my_list += [i] 
  elif s > 0:
    s -= 1
    continue

print(my_list)
```